# Modal UIViewController doesn't appear

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, initialization, modalviewcontroller

I'm attempting to load a Modal View Controller (1st) from a Modal View Controller (2nd). While it sounds complicated, it probably isn't.

The 1st controller is actually a UIWebView which is initialized in the loadView method of the .m file:

```
- (void)loadView {

    // Initialize webview and add as a subview to LandscapeController's view
    myWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    //CGRect forceframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    //myWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:forceframe] autorelease];
    myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    myWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);  
    myWebView.delegate = self;
    self.view = myWebView; 
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load HTML file as an NSURL request
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:updated_html baseURL:nil];

    // Invoke the covering modal view on condition
    if (some_condition) {
        landscapeCoverController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandscapeCoverController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self presentModalViewController:landscapeCoverController animated:YES];
        [landscapeCoverController release]; 
    }
```

The intended 2nd Modal View Controller (landscapeCoverController) is initialized with a NIB that I set up in IB.

My intended objective, is to conditionally cover up the UIWebView with the "LandscapeCoverController" view, which will have some buttons and interactivity which will result in the 2nd Modal View being dismissed.

Why isn't my landscapeCoverController loading? Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Also...the 1st Modal View controller (LandscapeViewController) .h looks like:

```
@class LandscapeCoverController;

@interface LandscapeViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView *myWebView;

    LandscapeViewController *landscapeCoverController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *myWebView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) LandscapeViewController *landscapeCoverController; // Modal view controller
```

and...the 2nd Modal View controller (landscapeCoverController) viewDidLoad does nothing:

```
// NIB initialized in LandscapeViewController.m viewDidLoad:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

as I think the

```
landscapeCoverController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandscapeCoverController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:landscapeCoverController animated:YES];
[landscapeCoverController release];
```

statement should handle initialization and loading of the controller...

Comment: Is `mainScreen` a view in your app?

Comment: @sudo rm -rf (nice name) mainScreen is a class method of UIScreen that returns a UIScreen object representing the bounds of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring landscapeCoverController as an instance of `LandscapeViewController`, and allocating it as a `UIViewController`. This is most likely your problem (probably the first one, as you aren't calling any methods specific to LandscapeViewController). Also, since landscapeCoverController is an instance variable, you don't really need to release it after `presentModalViewController`. Try to pick more dissimilar class names. It will save you from confusion like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Yeah, changed the type from LandscapeViewController to LandscapeCoverController. Still not getting the cover controller's view to appear...The LandscapeView (myWebView) appears perfectly - it's just supposed to be covered up by the CoverController's NIB view...

Comment: Did you change landscapeCoverController = [[UIViewController ...] to landscapeCoverController = [[LandscapeCoverController ...]? And make sure you have the view outlet in IB set.

Comment: Confirmed that I've made those changes, but still not seeing the landscapeCoverController view...

Comment: No errors in the IB project. There are 16 build warnings, 14 of which are related to an NSUserDefaults object being used in an unrelated view controller...@synthesize statements are all there. No delegates have been set up to dismiss the modal view...wonder if that's part of the problem...

Comment: Sly, how did you solved this issue ? I am running into the same thing right now.

Comment: It turns out the modal view controller must be called from viewDidAppear, in this case. See this for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516483/ios-display-modal-view-over-the-top-of-a-uiwebview