# iOS: display modal view over the top of a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, modalviewcontroller

Is it possible to display a modal view over the top of a UIWebView? I have a UIViewController that loads a WebView. I then want to push a Modal View Controller over the top so that a modal view covers up the WebView temporarily...

The WebView is working fine; here's how it's loaded in the View Controller:

```
- (void)loadView {

    // Initialize webview and add as a subview to LandscapeController's view
    myWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    myWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);  
    myWebView.delegate = self;
    self.view = myWebView; 
}
```

If I attempt to load a Modal View controller from within viewDidLoad, however, no modal view appears:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Edit dcftable.html with updated figures
    NSMutableString *updated_html = [self _updateHTML:@"dcftable"];

    // Load altered HTML file as an NSURL request
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:updated_html baseURL:nil];

    // If user hasn't paid for dcftable, then invoke the covering modal view
    if (some_condition) {

        LandscapeCoverController *landscapeCoverController = [[[LandscapeCoverController alloc] init] autorelease ];
        [self presentModalViewController:landscapeCoverController animated:YES];    
    }   


}
```

I suspect that there's something that needs to be done with the UIWebView delegate to get it to receive the new modal view...but can't find any discussion or examples of this anywhere...again, the objective is to invoke a modal view that covers over the top of the WebView.

Thanks for any thoughts in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same problem.  Moving the `presentModalViewController` call from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I actually got this to work, as you mention. I'm not sure I understand why this works...but at least it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone else reading this...the modal view doesn't actually achieve the effect I was aiming for here. Instead of being able to see the webview vaguely as a background, the background is completely whited out when the modal view comes up. Oh well...at least this might help someone out there anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work in `viewDidLoad` either, but I got it to work in a different method. Here's what I did:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...

    if (some_condition) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(showModal) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } 
}

- (void)showModal {
    LandscapeCoverController *landscapeCoverController = [[[LandscapeCoverController alloc] init] autorelease ];
    [self presentModalViewController:landscapeCoverController animated:YES];    
}
```

Basically, it works if it's not being called in `viewDidLoad`. I wish I could explain why, I'm curious myself, but this should at least fix your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Might be simpler to use `[self performSelector:@selector(showModal) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];` rather than a timer.

Comment: Hey, thanks donkim for the fast and complete response! In this case, the code you have doesn't actually work for me. Not sure why, but I think the modal view must be called from viewDidAppear.